# Swing control bar buttons space left on the side using flowLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/d7c6a740f79259f19ee42e52a1e74b9c.gif))</sub>

Can you see that there's line 1 or 2 px line on the very right side on the close button? for better quality select video: http://gyazo.com/d7c6a740f79259f19ee42e52a1e74b9c

[image: img]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/86818d65caecae44a1bbf5fdeed7530e.png))</sub>

I am not really sure what causing this. I am using FlowLayout as the component that holds all the buttons, and gridLayout for the main component's layout, and using BorderLayout for the JFrame's layout.

I tried to debug, but no luck.

I am new to layouts, they are awesome but sometimes hard.

This is my view class that takes care of the whole header part of the window:

```
public class ControllBar extends JPanel implements ViewComponent {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8031230498064473495L;
    
    private ControllbarController c;
    
    private JPanel close;
    private JPanel minimize;
    private JPanel down;
    
    public ControllBar(ControllbarController c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        super.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT, 0, 0));
        buttonsPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        
        JLabel text = new JLabel(c.getFrame().getTitle(), JLabel.LEFT);
        text.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        text.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 0));
        
        super.add(text);

        
        this.down = this.createToolButton(new Down(this, c), new ImageIcon("assets/down.png"));
        this.minimize = this.createToolButton(new Minimize(this, c), new ImageIcon("assets/minimize.png"));
        this.close = this.createToolButton(new Close(this, c), new ImageIcon("assets/close.png"));

        buttonsPanel.add(down);
        buttonsPanel.add(minimize);
        buttonsPanel.add(close);
        
        super.add(buttonsPanel);
        super.setBackground(new Color(0x8F8F8F));
        super.setSize(c.getFrame().getWidth(), 30);
    }
    
    private JPanel createToolButton(MouseListener listener, ImageIcon icon) {
        JPanel button = new JPanel();
        button.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30, 30));
        button.setBackground(new Color(0x8F8F8F));
        button.add(new JLabel(icon));   
        
        button.addMouseListener(listener);
        return button;
    }
}
```

And this is my Window class:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    public Window() {
        super(Screen.getTitle());
        super.setSize(new Dimension(Screen.getWidth(), Screen.getHeight()));
        super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        super.setUndecorated(true);
        super.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        super.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    }
    
    public void init(Collection<Controller<?>> list) {
        for (Controller<?> controller : list) {
            super.add(controller.getView(), controller.getPosition());
        }
    }
    
    public void setShowState(boolean b) {
        super.setVisible(b);
    }
}
```

The `ControllBar` component uses `BorderLayout.PAGE_START`, the body (the jpanel under it) uses `BorderLayout.CENTER`

What is really causing this little margin or padding on the side of the close button?
Let me know if you need more source(s).

## EDIT

This is causing it:

```
    JLabel text = new JLabel(c.getFrame().getTitle(), JLabel.LEFT);
    text.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    text.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 0));
    
    super.add(text);
```

why?

Comment: That part of the frame should look like every other frame on the OS, unless [`setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated-boolean-) is called..  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).

Comment: Edited, added the problem

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).